# Why does it say that my instance has no attribute x?

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have the following classes defined in python:

```
class ArcherDown:
    def draw(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self, newx, newy, direction):
        self.x+=newx
        self.y+=newy
        self.draw(self.x, self.y, direction)
    def shoot(self, x, y):
        print 'Shot!'

    def remove(self, x, y):
        pass

class Archer:
    def draw(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, newx, newy, direction):
        self.x+=newx
        self.y+=newy
        self.draw(self.x, self.y, direction)

    def shoot(self, x, y):
        print 'Shot!'

    def remove(self, x, y):
        pass
```

And I call them as such:

```
myarcher = Archer()
if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > myarcher.y:
    myarcher = ArcherDown()
else:
    myarcher = Archer()

myarcher.draw(myarcher.x, myarcher.y, 'right')
```

However, this raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 7, in <module>
    myarcher.draw(myarcher.x, myarcher.y, direction)
AttributeError: ArcherDown instance has no attribute 'x'
```

This only gives an error for `ArcherDown()`, not `Archer()`. Any idea why?

Also, when I add `__init__` as follows:

```
class ArcherDown:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
    def draw(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self, newx, newy, direction):
        self.x+=newx
        self.y+=newy
        self.draw(self.x, self.y, direction)
    def shoot(self, x, y):
        print 'Shot!'

    def remove(self, x, y):
        pass

class Archer:
    def draw(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, newx, newy, direction):
        self.x+=newx
        self.y+=newy
        self.draw(self.x, self.y, direction)

    def shoot(self, x, y):
        print 'Shot!'

    def remove(self, x, y):
        pass
```

`self.x` is always `100`, which I don't want.

I can tell that `x` is not defined in `ArcherDown()`, but then why is it working in `Archer()`?

Comment: Why do you expect the instance to have that attribute?

Comment: You should post some minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you never set an initial value for `x` and `y` in either `ArcherDown` or `Archer`. You can solve this problem by adding a method such as

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
```

to each class.

Comment: Then that should raise on this line itself: `if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > myarcher.y:`

Comment: Not if an `__init__` method was added to *both* classes, as I suggested, and called appropriately.

Comment: Note that the second half of the question was added *after* I post my answer.